# How to get tags in a jquery string to appear in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I want to add an element inside of another element, for example, a `<span>` inside of a `<p>` using jquery, the tags just appear as a string. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cpno334/) as an example:

HTML:

```
<button>
Click Me
</button>

<p>
This will have a red thing right here: ___.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
  color: white;
}

button:active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6);

}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('button').click(function(){

$('p').text("This will have a red thing right here: <span> The red thing! </span>")

});

});
```

Comment: change `.text()` to `.html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `html()` instead of `text()`

```
$('p').html("This will have a red thing right here: <span> The red thing! </span>")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/4cpno334/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just change .text() to .html()

```
$('p').html("This will have a red thing right here: <span> The red thing!   </span>")
```